# What is the verb for plasma formation?

Tags: terminology, plasma-physics

Simple question: what is the verb for the phase change from gas (or any other "regular" state of matter) to plasma? The best thing I can think of is "ionization into a plasma" but is there a nice, one-word equivalent counterpart to other phase change verbs like melting, boiling, subliming, etc?

Comment: You are correct in guessing the word. Gas > (ionisation) > plasma. Plasma > (deionization/recombination) > gas.

Comment: I’ve usually used ‘light a plasma’ for accelerators, semiconductor tools, etc. It starts glowing, kind of like a candle. Then you ‘quench’ it to turn it off.

Comment: I just use ionization (or ionisation if you are from the UK).